# How to remove checkout progress bar from one page checkout of magento only at login step

Tags: magento, checkout, progress

I am working on a project where client wants to remove progress bar only from login or register screen, I mean 'opc-login' step.

If I remove from xml 'checkout_onepage_index', it will remove from whole checkout. I just need for one step.

Tried to do it using css and jquery but its not working.

Below is my code in onepage.phtml

```
if(checkout.accordion.currentSection=='opc-login'){        
    alert('at login');
    jQuery('#checkout-progress-wrapper').hide();
    alert('after hide');
}else{
   alert('other than login step');
  jQuery('#checkout-progress-wrapper').show();
  alert('after show');
}
```

alerts are working correct but don't know why hide and show are not doing their job.

Is there any other way to achieve this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue. onepage.phtl is being called before right panel (progress.phtml).

So I moved code in progress.phtml and it works like charm.

But is there any better way to do this ?